# Why event target not passing through multiple react functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, react-props

So I am trying to make a textfield component in React that is highly reusable but whenever I try to access event.target.name or event.target.value I get empty data.

Is there any way to get this code to work?

```
function LoginForm() {
  const [form, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const printValues = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form.username, form.password);
  };

  const updateField = e => {
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const TextField = props => {
    return(
      <label>
        React Component:
        <input
          value={props.value}
          name='react'
          onChange={e => props.change(e)}
        />
      </label>
    )
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={printValues}>
      <TextField
        value={form.username}
        name='username'
        change={updateField}
      />
      <br />
      <TextField
        value={form.password}
        name='password'
        change={updateField}
      />
      <br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This code is an example that I have gotten to work. Why does this code work but not the code above?

```
function LoginForm() {
  const [form, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const printValues = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form.username, form.password);
  };

  const updateField = e => {
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={printValues}>
      <label>
        Username:
        <input
          value={form.username}
          name="username"
          onChange={updateField}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input
          value={form.password}
          name="password"
          type="password"
          onChange={updateField}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your child component   has it's name prop hardcoded `name='react'` and that's because your `[e.target.name]: e.targe.value` statement is not working, use `name={props.name}` instead and it would solve the problem.

```
 const TextField = props => {
    return(
      <label>
        React Component:
        <input
          value={props.value}
          name={props.name}
          onChange={e => props.change(e)}
        />
      </label>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code you show has a prop `change` instead of the `onChange` event listener in the TextField component.

I was looking here https://material-ui.com/es/components/text-fields/ because I never used material-ui, and in the example they still use the regular `onChange`.

So try changing `change` for `onChange`, as it is the only difference between both code examples besides the use of the component.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Rephrase the "Could you check if changing that solves the problem?" line.

Comment: That is a good point. In my project I tried that and I still got the same results but you are correct about changing change to onChange